# поиск на страничке

Tags: javascript

Народ, подскажите новичку.  Есть URL странички в интернете, там есть параграф  , который я хотел бы читать с помощью JS  и отображать у  себя на страничке онлайн. 
Как?

Comment: Juery load? Iframe?

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerText;`
Или
`var myPs = document.getElementsByTag("p");`
 Поиск нужного параграфа с помощью цикла и, например, startsWith
 `if (item.startsWith("Some text")){// дальнейшая логика по вставке текста на свой сайт}`

Comment: P.S. c JS в жизни не работал. Дал совет, исходя из принципов программирования и поверхностных знаний о языке, так что прошу не ругаться, если что